# How to get started adding fields in-browser that can be filled in on a PDF? (Like e-signature)

Tags: javascript, templates, canvas, flask, pdf-generation

There are a million websites that offer e-signatures, usually by letting you draw a rectangle on a PDF (or file that is converted to a PDF) where the signature will be placed.

I assume that this is using the Canvas element and AJAX to send the location where the rectangle was drawn back to the server.

My nonprofit already uses a great open source document assembly tool called Docassemble. I'd like to leverage our existing form library to allow for direct integration with signatures. I actually already built a Docassemble app that does e-signing, but you need to manually place the fields in the file before uploading it. Placing the signature location in-browser would make it exponentially better. Having to pass it off to a third-party is probably more than we can pay for but also would be much less useful.

I'm not a novice programmer but I've never used the Canvas element. I really don't know where to start with this project. Any advice? Are there any libraries that would help? Docassemble is built on Python/Flask with Jquery but this seems mostly like a generic JavaScript question. I have seen so many cheap Docusign clones with this feature that I wonder if there's a library that I can't find with my Google-fu.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad ([live demo](http://szimek.github.io/signature_pad/)) which has no external deps.

The example in the `docs/` directory implements a `Save PNG` button which downloads a PNG in the user's browser.  I was able to modify [these lines from the example](https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad/blob/028b538179ac1a56b190fb40b39821b8c39145b7/docs/js/app.js#L104-L105) to instead call my own upload function:

```
var dataURL = signaturePad.toDataURL();
// download(dataURL, "signature.png");
upload(dataURL)
```

This function makes the AJAX POST request:

```
function upload(data){
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', '/submit');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  xhr.onload = function() {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
          alert('Data submitted: ' + xhr.responseText);
      }
      else if (xhr.status !== 200) {
          alert('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
      }
  };
  xhr.send(encodeURI('data=' + data));
```

Now in my `/submit` route `request.form['data']` is an [inline image](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397) which can then be stored in the database, or rendered directly in the `src` attribute of an `<img>` tag.

Comment: This great but actually the problem I am trying to solve is let the user decide where on the PDF they want the signature to go. I want them to be able to put a marker on a certain position on the screen.